# 400 Bad Request even though docker image is running

Tags: docker, ubuntu, curl

I'm running a docker image using this command: `sudo docker run -d --publish 5001:80 -v backend-files:/Files test2`

After executing that command, I know the image is running because this is the output from `sudo docker ps`:
[image]

However when I try to make a call to the api that the docker image is running, I recieve a 400 Bad Request error as pictured below:

[image]

I'm not sure if I've provided all the necessary details to resolve this issue, so if any additional information is needed please let me know! Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Have you made sure, that there is infact an endpoint listening on `/`? and you are not supposed to call something like `/api/foo` or `/swagger`? From what you are showing us, a 404 might as well be correct.

Comment: You're right. After entering the correct endpoint I'm still having issues. I've updated the question.